# javascript popup does not get managed value

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I do not understand that when I press save in the form below I save the current contents of the inputTextArea, but when I want to look at a preview of the contents of inputTextArea I see the contents of the last saved mail template. What I should see is of course the current value of the textArea (after it is converted). Why does it not show the updated value of customMailTemplate?

```
<h:form id="gameMailForm" prependId="false" rendered="#{customizeGameMailBean.renderGameMailPanel}">
      <h:panelGrid columns="3">
      <h:inputTextarea
              styleClass="gameMailTextArea, textArea"
              id="gameMailTextArea"
              value="#{customizeGameMailBean.customMailTemplate}"
              converter="gameMailTemplateConverter"
              style="height: 120px; width: 300px; font-size: 11px;">
              <f:validator validatorId="gameMailValidator"/>
       </h:inputTextarea>
 <p:commandButton value="Save"
                  action="#{customizeGameMailBean.saveMailTemplate}"
                  ajax="false"/>
 <p:commandButton value="Preview"
                  ajax="true"
                  action="#{customizeGameMailBean.doNothing}"
                  oncomplete="javascript: window.open('gameMailPreview.jsp','Game Email','width=300,height=300')"
                  immediate="true"/>
</h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

gameMailPreview.jsp:

```
<%@page import="wmc.web.controller.CustomizeGameMailBean"%>
<%@page import="javax.faces.context.FacesContext"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<% CustomizeGameMailBean gameMailBean = (CustomizeGameMailBean) request.getSession().getAttribute("customizeGameMailBean");%>
<%=gameMailBean.getCustomMailPreview()%>
```

Is something maybe wrong about the timing?

By the way game doNothing is really doing nothing. It is an empty void method.

Comment: Eek, why isn't the `gameMailPreview.jsp` a JSF page?

Comment: That is because the customMailPreview is html code. I do not know how to put in html in a jsf page like this.

Comment: HTML is just allowed in a JSF page. Only in the ancient JSF 1.0 and 1.1 versions you need to do a little bit more, but it shouldn't be an issue on JSF 1.2 and newer, let alone JSF 2.0.

Comment: I agree fully with BalusC. JSP is absolutely not needed here (actually, it's almost never needed in a JSF app). In this case all you're outputting is customMailPreview, so a simple Facelet with a ui:composition and as body an h: output value="#{customizeGameMailBean.customMailPreview}" with escape="false" would most likely just work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the second command button has its immediate attribute set to true. This will cause the action method to be invoked in the apply request values phase, and thereafter skip immediately to render response.

In effect, no model values will be updated, thus you keep having the previous values in the model. Confusingly maybe, but the component will retain the value you just entered. I just didn't transfer to the model. For more information about this look up what the immediate attribute means in JSF and especially what it does when applied to a command button.

<sub>(I also would like to remark that using the session scope to communicate values to a popup is asking for trouble. This opens the door to all kinds of race conditions when the user has the page opened in multiple tabs or windows. If possible, you might be better off using Java EE 6's conversation scope.)</sub>

Comment: I only want the popup to show the preview. Nothing can be done in the popup window. It is not enough to change the immediate to false.

Comment: It should be enough, and it's irrelevant whether something can be done in the popup. But to be sure change the p:commandButton into a regular h:commandButton and don't use any ajax. Add break-points or system.out.println's to the setter for customMailTemplate. Also, what code is responsible for creating customMailPreview? Does it's getter create it on the fly from customMailTemplate?